# Is it possible to read geojson geometry from ArcGIS Javascript API?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geojson

I'd like to know if it is possible to read geojson geometries using the ArcGIS Javascript Api.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently only GeoJSON to Esri JSON has been developed. Also, note
>   that only geometries in the WGS84 coordinate system are supported

[image]

see sources:

http://esri.github.io/geojson-utils/examples/test.html

https://github.com/Esri/geojson-utils

Including https://github.com/Esri/Terraformer

Comment: You may also want to add [terraformer](https://github.com/Esri/Terraformer) to your answer

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm dealing with epsg:2154. Unfortunately, I cannot use Terraformer!

Answer (score 0):

its not necessary to manipulate WGS84 GeoJSON to get it into the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.  You can use the open source JSAPI plugin to load the features directly.

geojson-layer-js
https://github.com/Esri/geojson-layer-js

Comment: In the link you provided: "All GeoJSON data needs to be in geographic coordinates (wkid 4326)"

Comment: yup.  what's why I specified 'WGS84' GeoJSON in my answer.  this is a pretty common requirement for many utility GeoJSON JavaScript libraries.